# how to make decent sense from scattered river depth measurements

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, gps, interpolation, masking

I sampled river depth at scattered positions and I want to be able to make a map and GIS layers out of it.

My problems are:

1. As the river meanders the interpolation I do in scientific packages i,e. matlab generates values in points where there is no river therefore when I create a KML file out of it, it covers land areas. Does QGIS/GRASS have a better solution for that?
2. My GPS points accuracy of ~3m 90% of the time. Do I need to do any filtering for location?

Comment: Searching our site for [interpolation + barrier](http://gis.stackexchange.com/search?q=interpolation+barrier) turns up some relevant threads.

Comment: Interpolating is a pretty simple process.  In most cases interpolation is linear, though it can be done to suite any sort of curve that can be functionally defined.  If you choose to define your function as the set of related coordinates that currently define your river (say, by you drawing a curve that represents the river), then it is a simple matter of associating that function with the points you have sampled.  I'm going to say that Matlab is not yet sophisticated enough to interpolate such a complex shape without a little more help from you.  Add a few false points to help Matlab.

Comment: For interpolating a meandering river, you should use a flow oriented coordinate system. You can transform your data along the centerline of the river in Matlab using a method such as Merwade's "S-N" coordinate transformation. An implementation of that method is the [xy2sn](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/39796-xy2sn) function, which is available on the Matlab Fileexchange.

Comment: If you gps is ~3m for horizontal accuracy, the vertical accuracy is probably +- 10 m. What did you want to do with the elevation data?  Water typically flows at 1 m fall for every 10 000 m distance. So handheld gps accuracies are not useful for hydrological work.

Comment: With regard interpolation on a meandering feature, the most practical solution is to increase the number of samples.

Comment: @Willy Hmm... According to you, water in most parts of the North American continent, all of which lies within 300 * 10,000 m of the sea by river, will on average ("typically") descend only 300 m before it reaches the sea.  Given that most of the US lies above 300 m altitude--and a great deal is above 1000 m altitude--it sounds like our rivers are sticking right out into the sky above the coast and flying over the skyscrapers :-).  As far as GPS vertical accuracy goes, the O.P. is not proposing to use it for *elevations*: the question asks to interpolate *depths*.

Comment: OK, first for the meandering river interpolation when i did try to add zero depth point at the river banks but its not enough. i am still getting values on land (altough values of zero) which doesnt look too god when projected on aerial photo.

Comment: secondly, for the vertical gps accuracy, i do water level correction with dgps (my device is too slow to record tracks) and took the bottom depth using a sonar so i dont understand what i was doing wrong

Comment: Could you post a diagram of the results you are getting vs. the results you expect?

Comment: @whuber, thanks for helping on this, I limit my comment to the flow of water per se, not topography.

Comment: Hi all. as for the original question, i think i found an answer here: http://linfiniti.com/2010/11/raster-masks-in-qgisfossgis/.  but now I am facing a different question similar to the one presented here, i guess jakes comment is making taking me closer to the solution.